# Power series expansions for complex numbers about given point/largest disc for valid series?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

(1) $e^z$ about $z=πi$.

I simply wrote $e^z = 1 + z + z^2/2 + z^3/6 + \dots$ and noted that, since $e^z$ is entire, its series is valid for disc in infinite radius about $πi$.

(2) $\displaystyle\frac{z^2}{1-z}$ about $z=0$.

I wrote $$\frac{z^2}{1-z} = z^2(1 + z + z^2 + \dots).$$ This series converges when the modulus of $z$ is less than $1$. So we have an open disc with a unit radius and center at $0$.

Am I missing any key information?

Comment: "About $a$" means to use the form $$\sum_{n \geq 0} f^{(n)}(a) \frac{(x-a)^n}{n!},$$ your first series is about 0, not $\pi i$.

Answer (score 1):

Your first series is a power series about $0$, not about $\pi i$. You should have written\begin{align}e^z&=e^{z-\pi i+\pi i}\\&=-e^{z-\pi i}\\&=-1-(z-\pi i)-\frac1{2!}(z-\pi i)^2-\frac1{3!}(z-\pi i)^3-\cdots\end{align}

The other one is not a power series. You should have obtained$$z^2+z^3+z^4+z^5+\cdots$$